# Implementing babel transform-es2015-arrow-functions plugin to webpack config

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

When I add ES6 arrow functions to one of my components, webpack logs a syntax error. I have installed `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions`, but I don't know how to instruct my webpack build to utilise the plugin.

Would appreciate if someone could take a look at my config file and show me where it needs to be included:

**webpack.config.js**

```
"use strict";

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  devtool: debug ? 'inline-sourcemap' : null,
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'app-client.js'),
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 3333,
    contentBase: "src/static/",
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: '/index-static.html'
    }
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'static', 'js'),
    publicPath: "/js/",
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      loader: ['babel-loader'],
      query: {
        cacheDirectory: 'babel_cache',
        presets: debug ? ['react', 'es2015', 'react-hmre'] : ['react', 'es2015']
      }
    }]
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: { warnings: false },
      mangle: true,
      sourcemap: false,
      beautify: false,
      dead_code: true
    }),
  ]
};
```

Also, is it possible to deal with all ES2015-transforms with one plugin? Do you really need a separate plugin for every ES6 feature?

Thanks in advance.

---

### UPDATE

This is my component that is failing to compile properly:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

class Counter extends Component {

   add = (a + b) => {
      return a + b;
   }


  render() {
    return (
      <p>
         add(6, 9)
      </p>
    )
  }
}

export default Counter
```

Console logs:

```
 Errors while compiling.
client?692d:75 ./src/components/Counter.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (5:7)

  3 | class Counter extends Component {
  4 | 
> 5 |    add = (a + b) => {
    |        ^
  6 |       return a + b;
  7 |    }
  8 | 

BabelLoaderError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (5:7)

  3 | class Counter extends Component {
  4 | 
> 5 |    add = (a + b) => {
    |        ^
  6 |       return a + b;
  7 |    }
  8 |
```

Comment: It seems you are using the es2015 preset which includes all the ES6 transforms already. Maybe your `test` condition isn't working properly?

Comment: Yeah I just realised that :) Well, it's optimising my .jsx and my module statements so both the react and es2015 plugins are obviously working, but it seems to be omitting the arrow functions.

Comment: That seems quite unlikely.

Comment: It does seem unlikely. But it is happening :)

Comment: Please see update for component in question and resulting console log...

Comment: You are trying to use a **proposed feature**. It's neither part of ES2015, ES2016 or ES2017. You have to load https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/ or https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/ . This has nothing to do with arrow functions.

Comment: `(a + b)` is a syntax error too.